# How do i create a for loop to create 225 new users with 15 first names and 15 lastnames?

Tags: shell-script, for

I need to create 225 new users with add user but i have only 15 first names and 15 last names. I also need to create an automatic password for each user. Please help.

Comment: You should provide more information. If you have only 15 names, how do you want to name the rest of the users ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. You haven't even told us what operating system you are using! We also need to see the names you mention and you need to tell us what we should do with those names. Use random combinations? All possible combinations? What do the first and last names have to do with the username? Should they be the same? Similar?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify how the password or username should be formed. Here you have an idea how to do it for three names and three surnames. Just add names up to 15 and surnames up to 15, too, and you will get 225 usernames.

```
for name in name1 name2 name3; do
    for surname in surname1 surname2 surname3; do
        adduser $name$surname -p $name$surname
    done
done
```

You can form usernames and password differently, but you did not specify how.

I believe I should not provide an answer here, because that is obviously a homework.